# Should the FAQ Description of Board and Card Games reflect both Board and Card games?

Tags: discussion

Currently the FAQ description of this site (which I see is appended to any question that is migrated from this site to another SE site) includes the lines.

> This question came from our site for people who like playing board
>   games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board
>   games.

Similarly the FAQ contains the lines

> Board and Card Games - Stack Exchange is for people who like playing
>   board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing
>   board games.

After which the FAQ then goes onto further define what that actually means.  On first sight this seems to exclude a number of games which are on topic for boardgames.se.  I am thinking particularly about both traditional card and collectable card games which by most peoples definition would not be defined as a board game.  Is it possible to make these lines in the site strap line and FAQ reflect this site better and demonstrate that the site is in fact more inclusive than it currently appears.

Answer (score 3):

While I'm not opposed to changing the [FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq), we should focus on what the right change is.  The very section you quoted is immediately followed by:

> How do we define Board Games?
>
> Please see this meta question for the full discussion, the summary is:
>
> - Be playable on or around a table
> - Have objective rules of play and win conditions
> - Offer dynamic challenges, either through other players, randomization, or both
> - Be playable by hand, by human players implementing all of the rules

To me, as the site is boardgames.stackexchange.com we need to define ourselves based on that name and then explain what "Boardgames" means to us.

Perhaps a list of examples should be added?  Something like

Settlers of Catan, Poker, Dominion, Chess, Go, Magic:The Gathering, Bridge, Warhammer 40k?  I'm sure we could argue endlessly about which games to include, but would the basic concept satisfy you?

Comment: Agree entirely that the right change is difficult.  The way that I see the problem is not with the FAQ itself but the fact that the site strapline "This question came from our site for people who like playing board games, designing board games or modifying the rules of existing board games" that is used on other sites (effectively advertising this site) does not truly reflect the nature of this site.

Comment: @AlexC - what would you propose as a change?  As of yet, noone has suggested anything that is universally regarded as "better"

Comment: We come back to the same question that is taking place on the discussion about the URL.  There seems to be strong consensus that the site is not about Board Games, but rather about Table Top Games, of which board games are a notable part.

Comment: How about 'This question came from our site for people who like playing, designing or modifying the rules of existing board and card games.'

Comment: I like the idea of including specific examples a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Given the consensus on meta as the beta has continued, I believe the FAQ should be updated to reflect the current state of on topic areas.