# FAQ Update - suggest example games

Tags: discussion

Based on a [recent meta discussion](https://boardgames.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/599/should-the-faq-description-of-board-and-card-games-reflect-both-board-and-card-ga/602#602) I've updated the [FAQ](https://boardgames.stackexchange.com/faq#questions) to include a concrete list of example games.  I grouped them into categories that made sense to me and made sure to include the top 10 games based on current question count.

Please take a glance at it and suggest changes/improvements.  If a change is popular or blatently better than what I've done, I can make the change.

Answer (score 3):

Thanks Pat, the updated FAQ looks much more relevant to our current site.

One thing I find missing is a direct reference to something like Warhammer 40k or similar, figurine based games.  It is certainly implicit from the faq, but since the point is to become more explicit we should probably follow with the current consensus which seems to be

- figurine based games are on topic
- questions that directly related to the preparation of the pieces are on topic

In the second point, this would relate to filing (ie flashing), priming, painting, basing, weighting and so on.

I don't know how much these issues directly relate to the actual game play, but it's certainly more relevant to their games than customizing chess pieces would be (which I  think would be off topic).  For lack of a better site to suggest these questions be directed and based on questions already accepted as on topic I think it's worth adding.

Comment: good call, I knew I'd forget something :)  I'll make the change when I have a spare moment later today.  Thanks!